# Why is this C++ code only marginally faster than Python?

Tags: python, c++, performance, optimization, signal-processing

I converted some python code into c++ hoping for some performance benefits but found that the c++ implementation was only marginally faster. The code I'm converting is an sos filter from the scipy library. My python test is;

```
a_wgt_coefs = [[0.2343006, 0.46860119, 0.2343006, 1., -0.22455845, 0.01260662],
               [1., -2., 1., 1., -1.89387049, 0.89515977, ],
               [1., -2., 1., 1., -1.99461446, 0.99462171]]

# Define input signal
fs = 48000
T = 1.0
N = int(fs * T)
t = np.linspace(0, T, N)

ip_signal = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 440 * t)

# Filter signal
num_runs = 1000


def main():
    durations = 0
    for n in range(num_runs):
        t_start = perf_counter()
        op_signal = signal.sosfilt(a_wgt_coefs, ip_signal)
        t_end = perf_counter()
        durations = durations + (t_end - t_start)
    avg_duration = durations / num_runs
    print(f'Average execution time = {avg_duration} seconds')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The C++ code is a line for line translation of the scipy _sosfilt function, which I've imlemented as so;

```
inline void sosfilt_cls_4(float sos[3][6], float x[SAMPLE_RATE]) {
    float x_n = 0, x_c = 0;
    float zi[3][2] = { 0 };
    // iterate over every i sample section
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SAMPLE_RATE; ++i)
    {
        x_c = x[i];
        // iterate over every j section sample
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            float* section = sos[j];
            float* zi_n = zi[j];
            x_n = section[0] * x_c + zi_n[0];
            zi_n[0] = section[1] * x_c - section[4] * x_n + zi_n[1];
            zi_n[1] = section[2] * x_c - section[5] * x_n;
            x_c = x_n;
        }
        x[i] = x_c;
    }
    return;
}
```

I benchmared this using std::chrono;

```
float input_array[SAMPLE_RATE];
float sum = 0;

float sos_fs_48k_array_flt[3][6] = {{0.2343006f,   0.46860119f,  0.2343006f,   1.f, -0.22455845f,  0.01260662f},
 { 1.f, -2.f,          1.f,          1.f, -1.89387049f,  0.89515977f,},
 { 1.f, -2.f,          1.f,          1.f, -1.99461446f,  0.99462171f} };

int main()
{
    auto lin = linspace(0.0, 1.0, double(samples));

    std::cout << "Testing\n\n";
    for (int x = 0; x < runs; x++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < samples; x++) {
            input_col_vector(x, 0) = sin(2 * M_PI * 440 * lin.coeff(x, 0));
            input_array[x] = sin(2 * M_PI * 440 * lin.coeff(x, 0));
        }
        auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        sosfilt_cls_4(sos_fs_48k_array_flt, input_array);
        auto stop = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);
        sum += elapsed.count();

    }
    std::cout << "Average time:\t" << (sum / runs)/ 1e6 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "End.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The python code runs in 0.0002448 seconds averaged over 1000 runs. The c++ code by comparison runs in 0.0002336 seconds averaged over 1000 runs.

I've set my compiler options in visual studio to prioritise speed over space, with the Ox flag set. I'm also using the fp:fast floating point model and also AVX2 enhanced instruction sets.

Other things I've done to improve speed is allocating all input data in the stack, using floats instead of doubles but they haven't really made a difference.

Oddly enough, over a single run, the c++ code is way faster, running in 0.0002333 compared to python which takes 0.00045

**update: I am now getting 0.00012 seconds**

I put the function in the main.cpp file and started in a fresh project with default optimizations.;

```
template<typename T>
inline void sosfilt(T sos[3][6], T x[SAMPLE_RATE]) {
    T x_n = 0, x_c = 0;
    T zi[3][2] = { 0 };
    // iterate over every i sample section
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SAMPLE_RATE; ++i)
    {
        x_c = x[i];
        // iterate over every j section sample
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            T* section = sos[j];
            T* zi_n = zi[j];
            x_n = section[0] * x_c + zi_n[0];
            zi_n[0] = section[1] * x_c - section[4] * x_n + zi_n[1];
            zi_n[1] = section[2] * x_c - section[5] * x_n;
            x_c = x_n;
        }
        x[i] = x_c;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: The scipy library probably uses optimized C or C++ code internally.

Comment: I believe you will have a hard time beating these scientific/mathematical packages.. like @Barmar said, it probably uses optimized native routines internally.  You would just be saving the expense of the python -> native jump, which is negligible in such a case.

Comment: I thought removing the indirection of python would boost the speed significantly.

Comment: Given that @Barmar is probably correct, you still get about 5% speed increase with the C++ code which is not insignificant. However, also keep in mind that performance measurements like these are not 100% accurate.

Comment: @Ozymandias *I thought removing the indirection of python would boost the speed significantly* -- Just be aware that you are comparing code that has probably been optimized throughout its lifetime by very intelligent programmers, and your version which you have not had a chance to improve over time.  These types of comparisons rarely, if ever, go in the favor of the home-made version of the code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm getting .00012 seconds now. I put the sos filter above my int main function and it started working much faster, though I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 3):

The function you are replicating is implemented in Cython, see https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.7.1/scipy/signal/_sosfilt.pyx.

It is also specialized for the `float` case. So if it is written carefully (which I assume it is), it probably never has to call back into Python and is effectively pure C code, compiled as C, with a bit of different syntax, and effectively equivalent to your code.

Comment: I started a new project with default optimizations. Now my code runs in half the time python does.

Comment: @Ozymandias What I said still holds. They should be about equivalent. If your code is written as in the question, it has the benefit that it does know the array sizes at compile-time and can optimize for them and there is less constant overhead without the python calls dispatching to the function. The exact timing will also depend on compiler used etc.

Comment: For floating point operations without `-ffast-math`, also the precise ordering of operations matters. I haven't checked whether you translated this exactly from the original code.

Comment: It's an exact translation of the sosfilt function from scipy. I did a more naive implementation of an sos filter before this but there wasn't much of a performance gain. This version is line for line the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

scipy/numpy basically call into optimized numerics libraries which are written in C/Fortran/C++.

The only additional overhead is converting to/from python types, which is pretty quick with the cpython api.